# Move a Grid vertically WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation

I have a WPF window in which i want to make a side panel which appears slowly from left towards right on a button click . and after work done this grid should move back to left and disappear on another button click .
How to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easily achievable with WPF animations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312(v=vs.110).aspx (WPF Animations)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531289(v=vs.90).aspx (Creating event handlers)

For your case, you want to animate TranslateTransform:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746981(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I find it .
but here is a problem now how can i hide the Gird ?
When i set it left margin in minus then the window also occupy that space too ?? How to get out of this problem ?

Comment: You don't play with margin. All that you need is RenderTransform -> TranslateTransform.X property animation, as on my latest link. If you animate it to negative, ex: from 0 to -controlWidth, it will be hidden automatically, alternatively you can chain animations and just set Visbility to hidden after first animation is done(see my last link)